# Using JMSCorrelationId as selector while receiving Jms message from queue

Tags: citrus-framework

How can I get JMSCorrelationID with CitrusFramework. Any headers we add with header() are dropped by application so I would like to use JMSCorrelationID as selector while receiving message from queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in the reference documentation Citrus uses special JMS header names for reserved JMS headers such as `JMSCorrelationID` (http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#jms-message-headers) You should use `citrus_jms_correlationId` header name when setting/getting the header.

This header name should also work in message selectors in Citrus.

Comment: Thanks Christoph! I set header correctly by using citrus_jms_correlationId. However selector does not work for me with selector("citrus_jms_correlationId = 'JMSCorrelationID'). It worked by changing to selector("JMSCorrelationID = 'ID:${JMSCorrelationID}'")